# setBackgroundcolor error in the onitemclicklistener

Tags: kotlin

I want items to change color when the user selects them. But when an item changes color, another item changes in the same way, I don't know why this error occurs, this is the code

I am using a listview and a simpleCursorAdapter, with a LoaderManager.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    var cols=listOf<String>(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY
    ).toTypedArray()
    lateinit  var listView1:ListView
    lateinit var adapter:SimpleCursorAdapter
    lateinit var cursor:Cursor
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,Array(1){ Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},111)
        }else {
            var from=listOf<String>(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ).toTypedArray()
            var to = intArrayOf(R.id.name)

            adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item_contacts,
                null,
                from,
                to,0)
            listView1=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView1) as ListView

            LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(1, null, this)
        }
        listView1.onItemClickListener=this
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode==111 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(1,null,this)

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
        return CursorLoader(applicationContext,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            cols,
            null,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
        )

    }

    override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, data: Cursor?) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data)
        listView1.adapter=adapter


    }

    override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Cursor>) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null)
        listView1.adapter=adapter

    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

        view?.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(96,189,189,189))

    }

}
```

And this is the result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f04Vf.png)

example: when pressing the name of "angela" the name of "center of attention" is marked

I don't know if there is any other function that I don't know, it should be noted that I am a beginner in Android programming.

Comment: There's not enough information here. Is this in a `RecyclerView`? Are the contents of the two items identical?

Comment: At a guess, this is a ``RecyclerView`` and you're changing the colour of one of the ``ViewHolders``, which means when it gets used to display another item in the list, that will still have the same "selected" colour. The usual way to handle this sort of thing is to style the view in ``onBindViewHolder``, and set the background to **either** the selected colour **or** the unselected one - so it always gets set to the correct colour whenever an item is displayed. You'd need a way to store a value/list of the currently selected item(s), and check if the current item is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable view recycling by doing this

```
adapter = object : SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this,
    R.layout.list_item_contacts,
    null,
    from,
    to,
    0
) {
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position
    override fun getViewTypeCount() = count
}
```